# What is the policy for tag and tag wikis creation during the limited private beta?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

It's just GenAI Stack Exchange day 2, and we already have "too many obscure" tags.

Do we want to allow to create tags freely, and in such case, what will be the criteria to create tag wikis?

---

Some facts about tags:

1. Tags haven't any questions are automatically deleted.
2. Tag wikis of deleted tags become orphaned. Diamond users might recover the tag wiki content.
3. Tags used only on a question, not having a tag wiki, are automatically deleted after six months in Q&A sites and after 12 months on per-site / child Meta sites.
4. Questions with only one tag will be untagged if their only tag is automatically deleted or if the question is migrated when the destination site has the question tag.

## References

- [What causes a question to be tagged as [untagged]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167879/1359324)

Comment: I think at this stage it's fine to create them freely.

Comment: Note: single-use tags are auto-deleted after some time (I think it's a few months).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Only if the tag hasn't a tag wiki :)