# Do we really need a "prompt-design" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there's a [prompt-design](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-design) tag. Do we really need this? It seems a little bit like a meta tag to me.

So far, each of the questions using that tag already tag with a particular technology.

Answer (score 3):

Not all of the questions in this site are about prompt or designing prompt. So, I think having the tag in a question can imply that the question is about having a prompt with a result that is not yet satisfied. In order to change the current result to what it is required in the question, one may likely need to modify the original prompt; hence, [prompt-design](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-design).

I myself have [my own question](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/21/some-of-my-important-points-being-ignored-in-text-to-image-generation-how-to-em) with said tag, and I think it definitely expresses what the question really is. Therefore, I think we need the tag, yes. Let's wait for other's feedback for more collective agreement.

Comment: yes, I saw your question, and saw that _it already had a tag for the specific technology_- an observation that I've also brought up in the question post. This response doesn't seem to address that concern.

Comment: @starball Having [tag:prompt-design] tag with a specific technology tag actually further expresses that the question is about designing prompt on that specific technology. I don't see any concerns there. What is the issue that you think it is going to cause?

Comment: I agree that we don't have enough information just yet to make a collective call on this one. We could find down the road that 90% of questions are about this, and it is a meta tag, on the other hand, we may find that other question types come up so the tag will have some use.

Answer (score 0):

It's too early to evaluate [prompt-design](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-design) as it only has four questions and no tag usage guidance.

Related

[What is the policy for tag and tag wikis creation during the limited private beta?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18/12)